# Search and Replace in a String

Tags: javascript

The code below loops through a string and removes any duplicates between the characters in the string and the ones passed in removeDuplicates(). So array will be equal to "iel" which works perfectly. If however I pass through a word with double letters like "grass" array will be equal to ra because both instances of s will be removed. I need to only remove one instance of the letter s and not both?

```
 var currentWord = "field";
 removeDuplicates(f,d);

 removeDuplicates:function(i, j){
      var arr = []
      var w = "";
      for(k=0;k<currentWord.length;k++){
           l = currentWord[k];
           arr.push(l);
           if(i === l){          
                arr.splice(i,1);
                index = arr.indexOf(i);
                arr.splice(index, 1);

            };

            if(j === l){
                index = arr.indexOf(j);
                arr.splice(index, 1);
                break;
            };
        }

        for(l=0;l<arr.length;l++){
            w += arr[l]   
        }

        return w;
    },
```

Comment: What's `f`, `d`, `i`, `j`, etc.? Please be clear in your code.

Comment: if you do: `indexOf` to get the first occurance, you can do a replaceall start at that indext + length characters and replace with empty string

Comment: @Jack i think those are suppose to be strings?

Comment: what about adding two variables letter1 = 0, letter2 = 0.. when you find a letter, increment whichever letter by 1. Then simply put an if statement: if ( letter1 === 0 ) look for it.. otherwise it will skip it?

Comment: "f" and "d" are the first and last letters in the string "field" sorry I left out the quotation marks. i and j are variables for whatever is being passed in removeDuplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are trying to find and replace (remove) matching characters in the string.

You could do something like this:

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gkzHX/***

```
function findAndReplace(a, b) {
    b.forEach(function(s) {
        a = a.replace(s, '');
    });
    return a;
}

console.log(findAndReplace("field", ['f', 'd'])); // returns iel
console.log(findAndReplace("grass", ['g', 's'])); // returns ras
```

`replace` replaces the first occurrence of the character in target string.

---

Also, as pointed out by @thg435 in the comments, you could pass the set as string instead of an array and then  convert it to array inside the function and then `reduce`ing it with the replace.

```
function findAndReplace(a, b) {
    return b.split("").reduce(function(a, s) {
        return a.replace(s, '');
    }, a);
}
```

Now you can pass the search characters as string:

```
console.log(findAndReplace("field", 'fd'));
console.log(findAndReplace("grass", 'gs'));
```

***The fiddle by @thg435: http://jsfiddle.net/gkzHX/1/***

Comment: Nice, although it would be more natural to use `reduce` for that: http://jsfiddle.net/gkzHX/1/

Comment: Thanks @thg435. That is actually neat. Added your comment to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `.replace()` method:

```
removeDuplicates: function() {
    var s = currentWord;

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
        s = s.replace(arguments[i], '');
    }

    return s;
}

removeDuplicates('f', 'd'); // iel
removeDuplicates('g', 's'); // ras
```